# Search results ordered by search-text-length/match length

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this simple mapping:

```
PUT testindex
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "edgeNGram"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "ngram" : {
                   "type": "edgeNGram",
                   "min_gram": 2,
                   "max_gram": 15
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
           "properties": {
               "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With these values:

```
PUT testindex/test/1 
{"name" : "Power"}
PUT testindex/test/2 
{"name" : "Pow"}
PUT testindex/test/3
{"name" : "PowerMax"}
PUT testindex/test/4
{"name" : "PowerRangers"}
```

And searched this:

```
GET testindex/test/_search
{
    "query": {
       "match": {
          "name": "Po"
       }
    }
}
```

And got:

```
PowerRangers
Power
Pow
PowerMax
```

All with the same score of `0.2876821`

Clearly, the closest result to "Po" is "Pow", and that I expect to receive first; but I don't.

How Should I modify my mapping to behave by this logic?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have a mapping that you can share? Your question is too broad, imo.

Answer (score 0):

I think scripted sorting is the solution, but it comes with a performance decrease drawback. See [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) more about this. And the query you can use is this:

```
GET testindex/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Po"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "_source['name'].value.length",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```